# React Router how to use data returned from a loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on implementing a new React Router. I am using the new `createBrowserRouter` and want to implement some `loader` API calls. I have my project set up to make these API calls properly, however I can't find any docs on how to actually handle this data.

I want to pass the response data down to my component but it isn't clear how I do this.

I have an API folder with this network request.

```js
export function getReasonTypes() {
  commonAxios
    .get('/api/ReasonTypes?activeOnly=true')
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
      return response.data
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

I import this function when I create my router:

```
function defaulNewAPIs() {
  const data = getReasonTypes()
  return { data }
}

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/:appTypeId?',
    element: <AppLayout />,
    loader: defaulNewAPIs,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <ReferralDetails status="new" />,
      },
    ],
  },
])

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <GenReMsal>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <AuthenticatedTemplate>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </AuthenticatedTemplate>
      <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
        <GenReLogin />
      </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </GenReMsal>
)
```

The above code successfully calls my api, and based on the console log I can see it fetches data correctly. How do I pass this data into my router elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getReasonTypes` function needs to return a value for the `defaulNewAPIs` route loader function to return to the route component.

- Return the Promise chain

  ```js
  export function getReasonTypes() {
    return commonAxios // <-- return Promise to defaultNewAPIs
      .get('/api/ReasonTypes?activeOnly=true')
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response.data; // <-- returned to getReasonTypes
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
      });
  }
  ```
- Use `async/await`

  ```js
  export async function getReasonTypes() {
    try {
      const response = await commonAxios.get('/api/ReasonTypes?activeOnly=true')
      console.log(response);
      return response.data; // <-- return value to defaultNewAPIs
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    };
  }
  ```

The `defaulNewAPIs` loader function should wait for the resolved value returned by the `getReasonTypes` function.

```js
async function defaultNewAPIs() {
  const data = await getReasonTypes();
  return { data };
}
```

The component that you want to read the loaded route state should use either the [useLoaderData](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-loader-data)

```js
import { useLoaderData } from 'react-router-dom';

const AppLayout = () => {
  const data = useLoaderData();

  ...
};
```

or [useRouteLoaderData](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-route-loader-data) hooks.

```js
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/:appTypeId?',
    id: "root",
    element: <AppLayout />,
    loader: defaultNewAPIs,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <ReferralDetails status="new" />,
      },
    ],
  },
])
```

```js
import { useRouteLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";

const ReferralDetails = ({ status }) => {
  const data = useRouteLoaderData("root");

  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Drew, I am not sure I fully understand. Looking at my code `getReasonTypes` does return a data object, however it looks like when I console log that `data` response I get undefined.

Comment: @tdammon The Promise chain returns a value back to the `getReasonTypes`, but `getReasonTypes` still needs to return that value to the loader. I seems to have neglected that the loader also need to `await` this resolved value. I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

Your almost done all you need to do in the AppLayout component is call the react router useLoaderData hook. [react router docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-loader-data)

Comment: I think this is on the right track however console logging the result of `let data = useLoaderData` gives me an object with `data:undefined`

Comment: yes after looking over your question again you are right my answer is only 1 part you also need to fix the getReasonTypes() function is not returning correctly see @DrewReese answer for your options how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks perfectly fine, but I it has one issue.

Instead of having a seperate function called defaultNewAPI ,pass the getReasonTypes function directly to the loader as Reference..

Then all you need to do in the AppLayout component is call the react router useLoaderData hook.